# Dynamic array only allocating one element

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

I have searched all over and have not found anything on this.

I have the following simple code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
int *newArray;
int size;

cout << "enter size: ";
cin >> size;
newArray = new int[size];

cin.get();
return 0;
```

For some reason, regardless of the number entered, the dynamic array always has only one element allocated. I am not getting any compiler errors or run time errors (other than the array issue). I have also tried

```
int *newArray;
newArray = new int[100];
```

and

```
const int SIZE = 100;
int *newArray;
newArray = new int[SIZE];
```

I get the same result.
I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 for my IDE if that makes a difference.
If anyone has any pointers (no pun intended) please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I set a break point and actually look at the array, it only shows that it has allocated one element. So the array size is 1. No matter what I do. And I wish I could use vectors, but for this case (school assignment) I have to use an array.

Comment: @FrozenFeet The problem is that you didn't fully read your debugger's documentation.  To view a pointer **and** all its elements, you have to coerce the debugger to do that, i.e. `newArray, 10` if you want to see 10 elements starting at the `newArray` pointer.  I won't post this as an answer, since the answer really doesn't fit the question since you *are* allocating more than 1 element.  User error.

Comment: Off-topic comment. You can run your program without debugging (usually with Ctrl+F5) and it will ask for any key before closing console window. So you don't need `cin.get()`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie. That was exactly it. I was misinterpreting the information that the compiler was giving me. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

`newArray` is not an array, it's just a pointer to some place in memory. It doesn't contain a number of elements, it's just an address in memory. When you do `newArray = new int[n]`, `sizeof(int)*n` bytes of memory are allocated and the address of this allocated space is saved in `newArray`.

Visual Studio only knows that `newArray` is a pointer to an int. So it just shows the one number at that address. It cannot know how much memory has been allocated there.

If you want to see more than the first `int`, open the memory view, type `newArray` as the address, set up it to show `int`s. You will see plain memory interpreted as integers, so you will see numbers from your array. But there will be no end of these `int`s. After your numbers, there will be garbage.

Another option to try (I'm not sure if it works though) is to add `(int[100])newArray` to the Watch window.

So memory is allocated, feel free to write and read it and don't forget to `delete[]` it.

Comment: That was it. I misinterpreted what I was getting from the compiler. Thank you for your response.

Comment: *"[Visual Studio] cannot know how much memory has been allocated there."* - On the contrary, with Visual Studio being the implementer of the CRT, it very much knows, how much memory has been allocated. This information is stored 'to the left' of the pointer returned from `operator new[]()` (i.e. towards lower addresses). The debugger doesn't display this information, because you can easily do this yourself. If you want to interpret a pointer as an array in the debugger, use the `var,[32]` syntax in a variable watch, to display the first 32 entries.

Comment: The entire list of available specifiers is available from [Format Specifiers in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx).